# How many instructions as a function of input size N?

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have the following code

```
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)
            {
               ...
            }
        }
```

How many times do we declare variables?

First time - `int cnt = 0;`

Second time - `int i = 0;`

Nth times - `int j = i+1;`

So the answer is `N+2`. I used Princeton analysis for this

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring15/cos226/lectures/14AnalysisOfAlgorithms.pdf

33 slide

This is right? Or compiler just reassigns a value of j? So we declare only 3 times?

Can you provide a deep explanation about this question(include assembler code)? And what about object type(not int)?

Comment: What do you mean by "declare"? The variables are only declared 3 times. Do you mean "initialised"?

Comment: Is it just me, or this sounds like homework?

Comment: Why 3? In each step we create a new variable j

Comment: It is not a homework! Just look at R.Sedgewick slides http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring15/cos226/lectures/14AnalysisOfAlgorithms.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could say that you *declare* `j` once or you *declare* `j` N times, as suited you, because *declare* is a matter of analysing the *source* only. So:

> I declared `j` once; inside just one loop.
>
> I declared `j` every time the loop was processed.

Are equally useful.

They both say something about the source code, and they both say **nothing** about what the computer does when it actually runs the code.

**Declaration is a matter of source code not running code. Algorithms are a matter of running code**.

Now, when it comes to the produced code, there will **probably** be a single piece of memory used for `j`, though that "memory" will very likely be a register rather than actual RAM.

The algorithm is O(n²) because it does work `n * n / 2 - n / 2` times, and ignoring the lower orders that means O(0.5n²) and ignoring constant multipliers that means O(n²).

Now consider:

```
int loops = (N + 3) / 4;
int i = 0;
switch(N % 4)
{
    case 0: 
    for (int j = ++i; j < N; ++j)
    {
        …
    }
    goto case 3;
    case 3:
    for (int j = ++i; j < N; ++j)
    {
        …
    }
    goto case 2;
    case 2:
    for (int j = ++i; j < N; ++j)
    {
        …
    }
    goto case 1;
    case 1:
    for (int j = ++i; j < N; ++j)
    {
        …
    }
    if (--loops > 0) goto case 0;
    break;
}
```

Here we have a very different structure that loops 4 times less often, but has the same result.

And it is also O(n) because it also does work `n * n / 2 - n / 2` times. The fact that it has `int j` in it 4 times means nothing. Consider further:

```
int loops = (N + 3) / 4;
int i = 0;
switch(N % 4)
{
    case 0: 
    for (int j = ++i; j < N; ++j)
    {
        …
    }
    goto case 3;
    case 3:
    for (int k = ++i; k < N; ++k)
    {
        …
    }
    goto case 2;
    case 2:
    for (int m = ++i; m < N; ++m)
    {
        …
    }
    goto case 1;
    case 1:
    for (int p = ++i; p < N; ++p)
    {
        …
    }
    if (--loops > 0) goto case 0;
    break;
}
```

There's really nothing different algorithmically here, though it "declares j" four times less often whatever way you look at it.

Declarations are not instructions. They say "we're going to use this way of talking about this thing", instructions say "do this…".

Answer (score 1):

> This is right? Or compiler just reassigns a value of j? So we declare only 3 times?

That's not correct question. As far as .net concerned the process is more complex then C/C++. Virtual machine operates on IL code. IL code for it should be a stack-based. IL code will be optimized to declare local variables to be used in stack before execution of method body. It does that by `.locals` directive. So virtual machine can use only one variable, the stack and manage memory in any way it wishes.

```
    int cnt = 0;
    int N = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; ++j)
        {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("cnt=" + cnt);
```

IL code:

```
    .locals init ([0] int32 cnt,
             [1] int32 N,
             [2] int32 i,
             [3] int32 j)
    IL_0000:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0001:  stloc.0
    IL_0002:  ldc.i4.s   100
    IL_0004:  stloc.1
    IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0
    IL_0006:  stloc.2
    IL_0007:  br.s       IL_001f
    IL_0009:  ldloc.2
    IL_000a:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_000b:  add                   // here we have on stack i + 1
    IL_000c:  stloc.3               // variable j set to what's on stack
    IL_000d:  br.s       IL_0017
    IL_000f:  ldloc.0
    IL_0010:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0011:  add
    IL_0012:  stloc.0
    IL_0013:  ldloc.3
    IL_0014:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_0015:  add
    IL_0016:  stloc.3               // variable j set
    IL_0017:  ldloc.3
    IL_0018:  ldloc.1
    IL_0019:  blt.s      IL_000f    // j < N compare (1th and 3th positions)
    IL_001b:  ldloc.2
    IL_001c:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_001d:  add
    IL_001e:  stloc.2
    IL_001f:  ldloc.2
    IL_0020:  ldloc.1
    IL_0021:  blt.s      IL_0009
    IL_0023:  ldstr      "cnt="
    IL_0028:  ldloc.0
    IL_0029:  box        [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_002e:  call       string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(object,
                                                                object)
    IL_0033:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0038:  ret
```

So it is better to talk about memory allocation based on stack not on individual variables.

PS. Some introduction to IL at [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3778/Introduction-to-IL-Assembly-Language).

Comment: So what is the answer for c#?

Comment: It does not declare `j` variable inside the inner loop N times.